# Function that finds 3D position of a point given its position in stereo images

Tags: c#, 3d, triangulation

Clarification: You have a point in 3D space and a stereo camera setup that captures the point in its left and right images.  Is there a function that uses the pixel coordinates of the point in both images (along with the intrinsic/extrinsic parameters of the stereo rig) and outputs the 3D coordinates of the point?

I've looked through the EMGU library and tried googling others that might have it, but I've had no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the images have been rectified

```
Z = (b * f) / (Xleft - Xright)
```

where

- Z = point Z coordinate in 3D space
- b = baseline = distance between stereo cameras
- f = focal length
- Xleft = x coordinate of point in left image
- Xright = x coordinate of point in right image

Comment: Do you mean stereo rectified? As in their epipolar lines are horizontal and coincident?  Also, does rectification make the focal lengths equal?

Comment: Exactly. Rectification doesn't change focal length, it should be a camera parameter and if I'm not mistaken stereo camera pairs should be composed of the same kind of camera so with the same focal length

Comment: Thank you for your help ghembo, I have one more question:  I've looked up that formula and it seems that f is actually supposed to be multiplied in the numerator rather than divided (source: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/09wi/Lects/lect16.pdf)... is this correct?